# How do I put names from table into dropdown menu?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to figure out why the dropdown doesnt show up of the list of teachers in my tables

```
include"teacher.php"
        <body onload="displayDate()">

        <img src="Raw Pictures/Header.jpg" style="width:100% ; height:15%">
        <img src="Raw Pictures/green.png" style="width:8%; height:11%; position:absolute; top:4% ;left: 3%">
        <br><br><br><div>
        Teacher:
        <select>

<option>echo $row</option>

       </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

then the teacher.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('teacher_account');

$sql = "SELECT facultyname FROM subj_eva";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {}
?>
```

I cant figure out how to show the teachers from database into dropdown box? how do I fix it?

Comment: Is that `echo` even in a loop?  There doesn't seem to be any server-side code in that first snippet aside from the `echo`.  Additionally, how about `echo $row['facultyname'];`?

Comment: I'm with David.  Your code first bit of code up there, does not have proper syntax at all. You can't combine php and html like that.

Comment: Don't use `sql` it is depreciated, http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Also you should really consider using mysqli or pdo instead of mysql.

Comment: why I get downvoted when im asking for help?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('teacher_account');

    $sql = "SELECT teachername,facultyname FROM subj_eva";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html>
<body onload="displayDate()">
    <img src="Raw Pictures/Header.jpg" 
         style="width:100% ; height:15%">
    <img src="Raw Pictures/green.png" 
         style="width:8%; height:11%; position:absolute; top:4% ;left: 3%">
    <div>
        Teacher:
        <select>
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $row['teachername'] ?>">
                <?= $row['teachername'] ?> (<?= $row['facultyname'] ?>)
            </option> 
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Of course the code can be separated into files, I bundled it for the sake of readability here. It probably makes sense to move those styling rules into a separate `css` file instead of using those ugly inline styles.

A side note: you are using the outdated and deprecated `mysql` extension. You should switch to either `mysqli` or `PDO` and learn about the security advantages of "prepared statements". Also you should not use the `root` account for normal database use. Create a less privileged account and only use the root account for administrative tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT facultyname FROM subj_eva";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option>$row['column']</option>";}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('teacher_account');

$sql = "SELECT facultyname FROM subj_eva";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
$row = $row .'<option>'. $result_array["facultyname"] .'</option>';
}
?>
```

and php for generate html file

```
<?php
include"teacher.php";
?>
        <body onload="displayDate()">

        <img src="Raw Pictures/Header.jpg" style="width:100% ; height:15%">
        <img src="Raw Pictures/green.png" style="width:8%; height:11%; position:absolute; top:4% ;left: 3%">
        <br><br><br><div>
        Teacher:
        <select>
<?php
echo $row;
?>
       </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```